# make progress bar or loading for json

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and ios programming.What I want to do is to make a loading icon or progress bar to be displayed when the app is trying to connect to web service to get data by json or posting data to web service.How Can I make that?
by the way , I use swiftyJASON to get json data from web service.

Thanks

Comment: You should read more about multithreading here http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial  
and about the useful loading indicator classes here
https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIActivityIndicatorView. Its exactly what you want, create it, place it in the middle of your view and let it animate.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/

However I should note, that its better to download data in background thread and let user play with your app, if you have the option, this is better approach, but if you have to wait for the json data, first option is fine.